# focus div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Concept: Focus the div when user click the Comment link. There was two link in my php page. one is `comment link` and another one is `readmore link`. The two link goes to the same page but i want to `focus the div element` when  click comment link .

Comment: Please show your HTML markup and any JavaScript you've already attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they both link to a page called `more.php` for example, the 'readmore' link could simply have the link:

```
href="more.php"
```

Whereas the 'comment' link could have something like:

```
href="more.php?comment=1#commentbox"
```

The `comment` querystring could then be used like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (getParameterByName("comment") == 1) {
       $(".commentbox").focus();
    }
});

function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

The `#comment` part of the URL is purely for anchor purposes to position the user on the correct part of the page.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to **scroll to** the div element, and not actually focus it. If so, then:

```
<a href="#id_of_div">comments</a>
```

If you do want to focus it then (after thinking very hard about whether you should use a more conventional user control, such as a button, instead):

1. Give the div a tabindex attribute
2. Call the focus method of the div

e.g.

```
<div id="foo" tabindex="0"> … </div>

document.getElementById('foo').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="commentContend" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" 
  style="width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<a href="#" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('commentContend').focus();return false;">
   Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

so simply use `$('selector').focus()` This would work great with inputs or textareas

Answer (score 0):

You can create a url like: http://mydomain.com/mypage.php#mysection, where #mysection is the section on the page you want to focus.

Before your section add an anchor like `<a name="mysection"/>`. Obviously you'll have one for "comment" and one for "readmore".

Comment: Don't use `<a name>`, it was superseded by `<* id>` when HTML 4 came out in the late 90s.

Comment: Quentin: the w3c treats them as more-or-less equivalent. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id

Comment: True, but it's still supported and it's also part of HTML5; and it sounds like it'll give him the solution without having to do a bunch of javascript inspection of the location bar on page load.

Comment: @mblase — and then it [deprecated name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html#a_changes)

Comment: @El Guapo — `<* id>` is also still supported, also part of HTML5, also doesn't require JavaScript but doesn't require extra elements to be inserted.

Comment: @Guapo: You originally said HTML 4, not XHTML 1.1 (which came out waaaay after the late 90s).

Comment: I didn't say <* id) wasn't supported... at least I didn't mean to say tht... I said <a name> was... @mblase... yeah... good point... LOL